# Can't save file using Ionic and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to save an image that I have obtained from an API and save in my application. I'm currently using Ionic 5 and Vue.js.

To save the image, I'm using the [ionic native file library.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file)

The thing is that I cannot get it to work either on Android, iOS or Web. I do not really understand how this library works, I've tried using it in two ways:

The first thing that I have tried is to use as a static method, but it did not work and all the parameters came back **null**.

```js
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

private async getImage(token: string, model: Model): Promise<Model> {
    const { thumbnailLink } = model.images;
    const response = await axios.get(thumbnailLink, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    File.writeFile(`${token}/model-${model.id}`, 'thumbnail.png', response.data);
}
```

The second method that I have tried is to instantiate the class, and it also did not worked it out.

```js
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

private async getImage(token: string, model: Model): Promise<Model> {
    const { thumbnailLink } = model.images;
    const response = await axios.get(thumbnailLink, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    (new File()).writeFile(`${token}/model-${model.id}`, 'thumbnail.png', response.data);
}
```

If anyone could help me figure it out what to do, I've been trying to solve for a day now. Thankyou!

Comment: In your second example, you import `File` from `file/ngx` but `ngx` stands for `angular version x`. I have never use Vue and Ionic, but in Angular, you need to inject File in the constructor of your class.

Answer (score 2):

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem

```
import { Plugins } from "@capacitor/core";
const { Filesystem } = Plugins;
```

later in your code

```
Filesystem.write(...)
```